# XCode 4.2 Installation error

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, dmg

I downloaded XCode 4.2 from apple developer website. after I download it and try to install, error message pops out saying "The Following Disk Image Couldn't be Opened , xcode_4.2_and_ios_5_      not recognized "   has anyone here experienced this kind of error?

Mac Os X 10.6.8

Thank you guys!

Comment: That is not correct. There is a version of Xcode 4.2 for Snow Leopard—it is just that you can only download it from the iOS Developer Centre when you are logged in as a registered developer. You cannot get it from the public Apple website, and you can't get it from the App store.

Comment: ok I've deleted in order not to mislead.

Comment: To clarify my comment above, my comment was to an earlier comment by Verbeia, not saying the original post was incorrect. :)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9883247/cant-update-xcode-4-2-error-please-consult-var-log-install-log-for-more-detai
Could be a signing error among other things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a corrupted disk image... may just have been a bad download. Restart your computer, and if you still have the same problem, re-download. (And obviously make sure you're downloading the Snow Leopard version of Xcode since you're running it on 10.6.8... but I'm sure you were, and that wouldn't in any case lead to the error you described.)