# How to solve xcode 4.2 installing error?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

I use macbook air and my system version is 10.6.8 snow leopard.

Because of the slow network,I give up the apple resources.I download an xcode4.2 with ios5 sdk from other websites.

This xcode didn't be verified.

How to install this xcode on my computer?

Did anybody meet this problem before?

I check the log from the installer,it said:

An error occurred while extracting files from the package “Dashcode.pkg”

Comment: Just wait for the download to complete from Apple's site, that should be the ONLY way you get official Apple tools, unless you're verifying multiple checksums after download. Even then, I know *I* wouldn't trust anything not from the Apple Developer site.

Comment: Well, [this person](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102872/xcode-4-2-installation-error) recently had a similar problem. However, the other issue is if you've downloaded it from "other websites", did you get the Snow Leopard version of the Xcode 4.2 installer (normally only available for download for logged-in registered iOS Developers, from Apple) or did you download the likely-to-be-much-more-widely-available Lion version of Xcode 4.2, which can be downloaded by anyone publicly from the Apple website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to go out on a limb here and suggest that the only reasonable answer to this question is—download an official copy of Xcode from Apple, and install that. It's not really possible for us to recommend anything else. If your network access is slow in your specific location in China, is it possible to get to a location that can offer you faster access?