# Can't update Xcode 4.2. Error: please consult var/log/install.log for more details?

Tags: ios, xcode

**UPDATE**: Since this question is getting some views, I figured I'd better highlight the fact that **I solved the problem** by simply **re-downloading Xcode from the Mac App Store**. Upon re-installing it even gave me a handy option to delete the previous version and replace it with the new one. Hopefully this helps everyone out there with the same problem! :)

So I'm trying to update my Xcode 4.2 which I downloaded from the app store, but I get this error when I use the 'Install Xcode.app' updater:

[image]

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong or how to fix it?

I'm not really sure what other information I should provide, so please just let me know if you want more info :)

Edit: Here is the full install.log (I think): http://pastebin.com/GTzkpL3X

This is an excerpt that actually shows the error:

> **Failed install preflight: Error Domain=PKInstallErrorDomain Code=102 "The package “DeveloperTools.pkg” is untrusted." UserInfo=0x7f9d5da29060 {NSLocalizedDescription=The package “DeveloperTools.pkg” is untrusted., NSURL=../Packages/DeveloperTools.pkg -- file://localhost/Applications/Install%20Xcode.app/Contents/Resources/Xcode.mpkg/, PKInstallPackageIdentifier=com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsLeo, NSUnderlyingError=0x7f9d5d9eab40 "The operation couldn’t be completed. CSSMERR_TP_CERT_EXPIRED"}**

Comment: Tell us the contents of `/var/log/install.log`.

Comment: I hope I got the right log, it's there now :)

Comment: Do you happen to be using Mac OS X Server?

Comment: Not that I know of, so probably not

Comment: What version of Mac OS X are you using?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

open Date & Time of the system preferences and set the date a year before (in my case, maybe preferable date could be the date before Xcode 4.3 released.), and my installation successfully completed.

Comment: Setting the date before the certification becomes valid doesn't work btw

Comment: It worked for me, thanks! I would rather change the date than re-installing the OS. Besides, in my case straight re-installation required updating the OS as well.

Answer (score 5):

The following error shows up in the log:

```
Error Domain=PKInstallErrorDomain Code=102 "The package “DeveloperTools.pkg” is untrusted." UserInfo=0x7f9d5da29060 {NSLocalizedDescription=The package “DeveloperTools.pkg” is untrusted. 
PKInstallPackageIdentifier=com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsLeo, NSUnderlyingError=0x7f9d5d9eab40 "The operation couldn’t be completed. CSSMERR_TP_CERT_EXPIRED"}
```

Looking around the internet I found the following suggestions:

1. Flattening the package

   http://managingosx.wordpress.com/2012/03/24/fixing-packages-with-expired-signatures/
2. Update your system software:

   https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/45771/xcode-4-2-install-for-snow-leopard-fails-with-an-openglapps-pkg
3. Reinstall OS:

   https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3827920

   https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2616364
4. Delete files related to Xcode:

   https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3828043

**edit:** reordered based on comments.

Comment: Thanks, I've got a lot to go through here, I wonder if it might even just be easy to re download Xcode not from the app store?

Comment: The latest version of Xcode is 4.3.2, perhaps installing that version will avoid the issue you're running into.

Comment: I don't know if non-app store installs are supported anymore.

Comment: I just ended up re-downloading Xcode from the app store. After installing it even gave me and easy option to delete the previous versions? So maybe this is intentional? I have no idea, but at least now I have the newest version :)

Comment: Flattening worked for me too, I would recommend you try that first.